# Python requests JSONDecodeError: Expecting value

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-requests-html

I'm working on a Project using Python(3.7) in which I'm making a post request to an API and trying to read the JSON response which is in the format below:

```
{
"meta": {
      "errorMsg": "<description of issue>",
... },
   "status": <server status code>
}
```

Here's what I have tried:

```
resp = requests.post(url, json=body, auth=auth)
error_message = '%s - %s' % (status_code, resp.json()['meta']['errorMsg'])
```

but its return an error as:

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char
>   0)

what can be wrong here? I have tried to read the `resp` with `.json` separately but with the same error.

Comment: Almost always this error points to you having [jsonlines](http://jsonlines.org/) and not regular JSON

Comment: Check `resp.text` to see what the response body actually looks like.

Comment: Is your API response is 200? did you check that?